# Unexpected output from SQL Server IN operator

Tags: sql-server-2012, in-operator

Consider the following tables. Mind the differing names of the id-columns.

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int)
CREATE TABLE B (bid int)
```

A contains values `1 to 10`. B contains values `1 to 5`.

Now, I wrote a query to find all rows that are present in both tables, by comparing their ids. By mistake, I wrote an incorrect query like this:

```
select id from A
 where id in (select id from B)
```

See how I forgot that the id column of `B` is named `bid`

What I don't understand is why this query executes and return all rows from `A`. If anything, I expected it to return `1 to 5`

Having a look at the execution plan doesn't help me. See how the table scan of table B actually return 10 rows in the image below.
[image]

So, is this really the expected behaviour of the query I wrote? I would expect an error message like `Invalid column name 'id'`, which is what I get when I run `select id from B` in isolation.

Comment: Inserting a few aliases I realized that this query is equivalent to the one in the question: `select a.id from A a where a.id in (select a.id from B b)`. So the "scope" of the outer select is somehow used in the sub-select. Still, this feels very sketchy...

Comment: If you do `..in (select B.id from B)` I guess it would throw an error? Leaving Sql to figure out the bindings is never a good idea :)

Comment: yep, you are both right! Thank you!